# How to resolve conflicts caused by .dll files?

Tags: git

I've a fix35 branch from master contains 20 .dll files. What I did was replacing several of them with the same name .dll files to fix a bug. Then what I wanted was merging fix35 into master. In other words, now I want master exactly the same as fix35.

But git told me 4 .dll files got conflicts, and I got to resolve them manually. For dlls, it looks like I can't manually edit them.

May you point me a right direction?

Comment: Why do you have dll files in source control in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should avoid the issue entirely by storing those generated dlls in a separate referential (typically a binary referential like Nexus or Artifactory)

The only binaries you might consider including in a Git repos are static ones (meaning, they are not generated/different from branch to branch, and won't be an issue on merges)

Answer (score 0):

First, find out who, how and why have changed the dlls in master:

```
git log fix35..origin/master -- DLL1 DLL2 DLL3 DLL4
```

this would show you the commits with author and commit message.

Then, decide if your version contains the changes already added to master

If it does, just use your version

```
git checkout --theirs -- DLL#
```

otherwise, you should make a dll which contains both changes, replace the file in working tree with it, and commit it:

```
git add DLL#
```